# If other languages are not defined show english

Tags: craft3, localization, multi-site

Is it possible to get the english content on the, for example, Spanish site if the Text for the specific language is not defined yet?

I do not mean a redirect! The English version should be displayed until the Spanish content has been inserted.

It would be great if someone has a Idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could choose which value to translate your content into using the `|t($lang)` filter based on some condition. You condition could be a lightswitch field on each entry saying whether it's been translated or not, or check if a content field is empty or not.

So something like

```
set lang = entry.lang

if entry.isTranslated == false {
   set lang = 'english'
}

{{ content|t(lang) }}
```

Comment: It would be really easy if this work, but it does not. But my theoretical Idea was like this. If Text Field is empty get English Text.

Answer (score 0):

I think it have something to do with `.handle('spanish')` or `.siteId('2')`. I tried it but seems to be more complicated than I thought.